# How use Xampp-control-panel for php program in linux

Tags: 12.04

I installed Xampp on my Ubuntu.
I wrote a PHP program for Hello World and saved it as MyFirstPhp.php in `opt/lampp/htdocs/MIKpatel/`
I opend the Xampp-Conytrol-panel

Problems:
1) I don't know what is the use of Xampp-control-panel
2) I don't know how php program run using xampp-control-panel.

Answer (score 0):

You cant run PHP scripts from the XAMPP control panel, it's purpose is to start/stop the XAMPP services.
In the control panel make sure `Apache` is started, if it`s not click on start.

Then open a browser and go the the URL: `localhost/MIKpatel/MyFirstPhp.php`.